# Magento 2: Override Price Model with plugin

Tags: magento2, magento-2.2.5

I need to override Price.php Model with plugin.
I've created PricePlugin inside Plugin folder.

```
<vendor>/<module>/Plugin/Product/View/Options/PricePlugin.php
```

**PricePlugin.php :**

```
<?php
namespace <vendor>\<module>\Plugin\Product\View\Options;

use \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config\Source\Product\Options\Price;

/**
 * Class AbstractOptions
 * @package <vendor>\<module>\Plugin\Product\View\Options
 */
class PricePlugin
{
    const VALUE_FIXED = 'fixed';
    const VALUE_PERCENT = 'percent';

    /**
     * @param Price $price
     * @return array
     */
    public function toOptionArray(Price $price)
    {
        return [
            ['value' => self::VALUE_FIXED, 'label' => __('Fixed')],
            ['value' => self::VALUE_FIXED, 'label' => __('Per Character')],
            ['value' => self::VALUE_PERCENT, 'label' => __('Percent')],
        ];
    }
}
```

**di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Config\Source\Product\Options\Price">
    <plugin name="VENDOR_MODULE_Model_Price" type="<Vendor>\<Module>\Plugin\Product\View\Options\PricePlugin" sortOrder="1" />
</type>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there , plugins can be used on three ways that are after , before and around . You just need to preappend any of this three to the method you want to make changes .

so change

> toOptionArray(Price $price)

to

> aftertoOptionArray(Price $price)

Also you can manipulate the result from the method you are overriding like you have done it like

```
public function aftertoOptionArray(Price $price)
    {
        return [
            ['value' => self::VALUE_FIXED, 'label' => __('Fixed')],
            ['value' => self::VALUE_FIXED, 'label' => __('Per Character')],
            ['value' => self::VALUE_PERCENT, 'label' => __('Percent')],
        ];
    }
```

you can change it to

```
public function aftertoOptionArray(Price $price, $OptionsArray)
    {
        // $OptionsArray here holds the values from the method toOptionArray() so you can simply add your value here which is ['value' => self::VALUE_FIXED, 'label' => __('Per Character')] into that array .
    }
```

Hope this helps